# Проверка на пустое значения поле средствами Html

Tags: html, css

Добрый день! Есть такое поле

```
<input type="text" name="fio" id="order_input" pattern="^[A-Za-zА-Яа-яЁё\s]+$" required=""/>
```

Если оно пустое то все нормально, выдает ошибку заполните поле, но если вбить просто пару пробелов то валидация не работает, хотя поле все еще пустое. Что делать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В Вашем варианте регэксп задает пробел как допустимый символ наряду с буквами, а не указывает что сначала буквы потом пробел. Поэтому нужно подлинней:

```
pattern="^[A-Za-zА-Яа-яЁё]+(\s[A-Za-zА-Яа-яЁё]+)*$"
```

То есть: сначала одна или более букв, потом ноль или более групп "один пробел и за ним одна или более букв".